# Unable to find a user-defined type in a c++ unordered set with custom operator==()

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, unordered-set

**Problem Statement:** Iterate over an array of objects and check if the object exists in an unordered_set.

**Goal:** I could have thousand of objects in one container to check their existence in millions of objects in another container. I choose unordered_set for its constant finding complexity and vector for iterating. I'm new to this and if you have any alternate approach, I'd really appreciate it.

**Issue:** unordered_set find isn't working as expected or I got the concept wrong!

**Main:**

```
int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Block>> vertices;

  vertices.push_back(std::make_unique<Block>("mod1", "work"));
  vertices.push_back(std::make_unique<Block>("mod2", "work"));
  vertices.push_back(std::make_unique<Block>("mod3", "work"));

  std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<Block>> undefs;

  undefs.insert(std::make_unique<Block>("mod1", "work"));
  undefs.insert(std::make_unique<Block>("mod2", "work"));

  for(auto& vertex : vertices) {
    auto search = undefs.find(vertex);
    if(search != undefs.end()){
      std::cout << "Block: " << vertex->getName() << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

**Block Class Overload:**

```
bool Block::operator==(std::unique_ptr<Block>& block) const {
  return block->getName() == mName;
}
```

**Expected Output:**

mod1

mod2

**Block:**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <memory>

using std::string;

class Block {
  private:
    string mName;
    string mLib;
  public:
    Block(string const& name, string const& lib);
    string getName() const;
    string getLib() const;
    bool operator==(std::unique_ptr<Block>& block) const;
};
```

Comment: what is the problem? What did you get as output? What did you expect?

Comment: Please be so kind to show us what `Block` is and what kind of error message the compiler gives you.

Comment: Const as an argument? as in `bool Block::operator==(const std::unique_ptr<Block>& block) const {`

Comment: I didn't get any error message and the code compiled correctly. But when I ran, I didn't get any output.

Comment: You block class overload `operator==` does not matter, because the objects in the vector and unordered_set are smart pointers.  The code is comparing the smart pointers, not the Block objects.

Comment: You are comparing pointers with pointers which just looks at addresses. `Block` never comes into play here so `Block::operator==` isn't considered. And since `find` only takes `unique_ptr`s it can't be made to work as you want. Use `std::find_if` instead.

Comment: Anyone can block->getName() be called on `std::unique_ptr<Block>& block` which is non const value?

Comment: @Rixment • const methods can be called on non-const objects.  But not vice versa: cannot call a non-const method on a const object.

Comment: When you define overloaded operator as a method it only will be used when object of this class on the left side, not pointer not smart pointer. You need standalone function that accepts 2 instances of `std::unique_ptr<Block>`

Comment: What's the solution then? Global `operator==(std::unique_ptr<Block>&, std::unique_ptr<Block>&)`? Or `operator==(Block&, Block&)` will suffice with implicit conversion from `std::unique_ptr<Block>` to `Block`?

Comment: Okay, one follow up question then: Will find_if have any impact on the performance/complexity if my unordered_set contain a million objects? [Also, I really appreciate all the comments, thanks.]

Comment: @SourabSharma No matter how you do this, you will need to inspect the value your pointers point to. This will probably be a bit slower than just comparing addresses but it's necessary. Whether this is through `find_if` or another scheme won't make much of a difference. So it's not `find_if` that will inherently have the performance hit.

Comment: I just added the goal. Any comment from @all on that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare pointers, not values.
You need to specify hashing function for class `Block`.

For example, if you want to use mName as key the code will be the following:

```
class Block {
private:
    string mName;
    string mLib;
public:
    Block(string const& name, string const& lib)
    {
        mName = name;
        mLib = lib;
    }
    string getName() const {
        return mName;
    };
    string getLib() const {
        return mLib;
    }
    bool operator==(const Block & block) const;
};

template<> struct std::hash<Block> {
    std::size_t operator()(const Block & block) const noexcept {
        return std::hash<std::string>{}(block.getName());
    }
};

bool Block::operator==(const Block & block) const {
    return block.getName() == mName;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Block> vertices;

    vertices.emplace_back(Block("mod1", "work"));
    vertices.emplace_back(Block("mod2", "work"));
    vertices.emplace_back(Block("mod3", "work"));

    std::unordered_set<Block> undefs;
    undefs.emplace(Block("mod1", "work"));
    undefs.emplace(Block("mod2", "work"));

    for (auto& vertex : vertices) {
        auto search = undefs.find(vertex);
        if (search != undefs.end()) {
            std::cout << "Block: " << vertex.getName() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood the issue. My only concern is storing object directly as compared to storing pointers pointing to them. As I explained in the Goal, I'm dealing with a large number of objects here and performance is my main priority.

Comment: @Sourab Sharma, if performance is important, I suggest you use hashing internally: you can calculate the hash for the mName (for instance) and use it as a key for your object. If you will operate internally mostly with these hashes and not the names it will be much faster than hashing strings each time. This is sometimes called "string inlining", but sometimes it means prefix trees, not hashing. For most cases hashing is optimal, especially if you don't have collisions

Comment: Whoops, I mean "string interning", not inlining :) I also highly recommend you to read the book "Game Engine Architecture" which describes many of such optimizations in terms of performance.

Comment: I think I've now got enough things to try and work with. Thanks again. And I'll check out the book as well.

Answer (score 2):

An `unordered_set` requires a hashing function and a comparison function. You are using the existing hashing and comparison functions for `std::unique_ptr`, which is definitely not what you want.

I would not suggest trying to change the behavior of `std::unique_ptr<Block>` because that will lead to confusion in other code that wants normal semantics for pointers. Instead, add normal hashing and comparison functions for `Block` and pass customized ones to the constructor of the `unordered_set`.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the issue. Any comment on the Goal part?

Comment: I'd just avoid `std::vector` unless you can right-size it before any insertions (with `reserve`). Otherwise, use `std::list`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is that you are trying to compare pointers, which are different!
I'dont know the reasons behind using unique_ptr<> but by doing that you are actually trying to compare identities, instead of states which is what you want.

So you can see what I mean, let's say the first Block object is at position 100 in your memory. That would be its identity. So we have object1 whose state is "mod1, work" and whose identity is 100. Then we have object2, whose identity is 150 but its state is the same as object1, "mod1, work".

All what you have both inside the vector and the unordered_set are pointers, so you have memory positions. When inserting them in the vector, you inserted, let's say, position 100. But in the unordered_set you inserted 150. They have the same state, but find method is looking for a memory position.

I hope my answer was helpful. If you find any mistakes here or think differently please let me know. Good luck! :)

Comment: I understood your point (very empathetically explained, thanks) but if I have to create millions of objects on the stack and store them in a container won't it be an issue as compared to storing pointers to them?

Comment: @SourabSharma A stack built on top of `std::list` stores pointers to the objects already. Just don't build on top of `std::vector`.

Comment: @SourabSharma what do you mean on the stack? If you use `std::vector`/any other container data is being stored on the heap using `new` internally(to be precise, this is defined by allocator). You are very unlikely to want to store millions of object on the stack. Usually, the stack does not exceed 10mb.

Comment: @espkk Okay I wasn't aware of this.